# C# create google calender event with google meet using GoogleApi.Calendar.V3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Want to create google events with google meet , I have following code it creates recurring meeting . but want to make google meet with it.

```
        var credential = await GetCredentialForApiAsync();

        var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "ASP.NET MVC5 Calendar Sample",
        };
        var service = new CalendarService(initializer);

        var ev = new Event();
        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime();
        start.DateTime = new DateTime(2021, 10, 11, 10, 0, 0);

        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime();
        end.DateTime = new DateTime(2021, 10, 15, 10, 30, 0);


        ev.Start = start;
        ev.End = end;
        ev.Summary = "New Event";
        ev.Description = "Description...";
        ev.HangoutLink = ""; ;

        var calendarId = "primary";
        
        Event recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(ev, calendarId).Execute();
```